# Is the use of servlet better than the action-classes in struts2?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts2

As it is known, that **Servlets** use individual threads for the respective *requests* and this improves the efficiency of server.
Whereas, in the struts2 framework, each mapped **Action-Class** has its own object been created for the respective *requests*.

Now, how is it a good practice(optimised) in struts2 to have individual objects as compared to just threads in ordinary servlets ? Why don't we just have servlets !?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a request comes in to a web container, the container takes a thread from a pool in order to execute the request. Once the request is handled, the thread goes back to the pool to be usable for subsequent requests. Several requests can be handled in parallel, because the pool has several threads available.

Each servlet you declare in your web app is instantiated only once by the web container. A single instance of each servlet is thus used by several concurrent threads. This is why your servlets must be thread-safe.

Struts doesn't change anything to the above. What it does is that it defines a single servlet or filter that handles *all* the requests. And for each request targeting the path of a given action, a new Struts Action instance is created. This is where the model with servlets differ. A servlet is a singleton (only one instance for all the requests), whereas a new Struts action is instantiated for every request.

The advantage is that the action doesn't need to be thread-safe, since it's used by onlyu one thread and is then discarded. It can contain intermediary state without any need for synchronization. The downside is that many instances are created. But since the Java garbage collector is very fast at recycling short-lived objects like Struts actions, it doesn't cause any problem in practice.

Comment: +1 for `It can contain intermediary state without any need for synchronization`